# Setting up nfs between Fedora 21 server and Rasperry Pi running OpenELEC

Tags: linux, networking, fedora, raspberry-pi, nfs

I'm trying to set up a home network to share my various audio and video files to different media server machines.  I currently have a machine running Fedora 21 which hosts all the files that I want to share.  In its /etc/exports file I have:

```
/home/Kodi *(ro)
```

Simple.  Short and sweet, and effective on 2 other machines.  From those machines I can easily execute

```
mount 192.168.1.144:/home/Kodi /nfs
```

And all is good.

On the Raspberry Pi I have installed OpenELEC as the OS, enabled SSH so that I can get in and do administrative tasks.  But, it never works.  Executing the same mount line with a modified target always gives:

```
mount: RPC: Remote system error - No route to host
mount: mounting 192.168.1.144:/home/Kodi on /storage/nfs/Kodi failed: Bad file descriptor
```

But, I can ping the server and I can even SSH to the server from the Raspberry Pi, so there really isn't a routing problem.  And, just to throw in another twist, if I boot the Raspberry Pi using Raspian, that works just fine.  It has to be something about OpenELEC, but I cannot figure out what.  I've also asked this question over at the OpenELEC forum (http://openelec.tv/forum/134-usage/76905-setting-up-nfs-with-rasppi-and-openelec) but I've gotten nowhere so far.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this
[wiki](http://wiki.openelec.tv/index.php/Mounting_network_shares) openelec
does not support nfsv4, so the mount must be using nfsv3. Perhaps all the
other systems are using nfsv4 and either a firewall is not letting nfsv3
through, or your server is only serving nfsv4.

"No route to host" is a typical message when you get an icmp packet back
from a firewall which misleads on the fact that the port is not allowed.
Try temporarily disabling the firewall on the server.

I dont know if fedora 21 still enables nfsv3 by default. If not you could
try this edit and restarting nfs with systemctl:

```
sed -i /etc/sysconfig/nfs -e '
/RPCNFSDARGS=/s/=.*/="--nfs-version 3 --nfs-version 4"/
/RPCMOUNTDOPTS=/s/=.*/="--nfs-version 3 --nfs-version 4"/'
```

Comment: Holy cow, that's it!  I disabled the firewall on the server and BAM!  I'm in.  Regarding the nfs version, I do see in Fedora 21 that is has both v4 and v3 enabled.  I was sure I had found the same on the OpenELEC machine, but maybe not. I can't seem to figure out how to get the nfs version on the OpenELEC at this point.  Now to figure out how to make the firewall on the Fedora machine allow the OpenELEC machine to see the nfs without fully disabling the service...

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem after upgrading my server to F21 from F20. Disabling the firewall altogether let Kodi find and mount the NFS shares, but I was uneasy about having no firewall at all on the server.

I've done:

```
firewall-cmd --add-port 1024-65534/tcp --add-port 1024-65534/udp --add-port 111/tcp --add-port 111/udp
```

Which opens up everything above the reserved ports, and the rpcbind port (111) as well. Simply doing

```
firewall-cmd --add-service nfs
```

simply isn't sufficient for the Kodi NFS client, although it's fine for another Fedora client to connect. Perhaps the Kodi client only speaks NFS v3?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Yes, I believe that OpenElec only supports nfs v3.  I'll give the port option a try.